# chart.js using linear for y labels and how to convert data to support this

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart that has data for x and y, and I just saw that I can use linear option on x. So I did this

```
xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear', 
            ticks:{
             min : 0,
              max : 60,
             stepSize : 5,
              fontColor : "#000",
              fontSize : 14
            },
```

but now my point are gone and I see that is because I need a scattered graph? I saw a guy that  converted the data to a format that works for a scatter chart but that function is not working for me and i  think a bit two specific to its use case.  My data is done like this.

```
data: {
        labels: labelData,
        datasets: Data
      },
```

the data is build with

```
for (var d =0; d < inData.length; d++)
    {
        labelData[d] = inData[d].DegOpt;
        Data[d] = inData[d].Freq;
    }
```

and the arrays of in data are just numbers. Is there a special way I need to build my label data to see it?